# How are people bypassing the limit?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How are people attacking me with more troops than they are supposed to be able to?
220 is the cap and I am being attacked with up to 245 housing spaces worth of troops.
Are they cheating, or I am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

### tl;dr:  4 x Level 7 Army Camp (55 troops) + Level 4 Clan Castle (25 troops) = 245 troops

It is possible you are thinking back to an older limit, but 245 is the new limit.  You don't have to [do anything fancy](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/13264-245-troops-Cheaters) to get 245, just max out your [Army Camps](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Army_Camp) and [Clan Castle](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Castle).  The level 7 Army Camp which allows 55 troops was introduced in the [Winter Update version](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/4493-Winter-update-%28Version-2-111%29-release-notes), so possibly you are thinking back to a time before level 7.

Also, I believe there was an undocumented change with the 3.54 patch which started to include the Clan Castle deployed troops in the overall troop count.  This means you will see 245 + the CC banner, but the banner doesn't mean 25 more troops it just tells you the opponent deployed CC troops (so the total is still 245).

Comment: Again Let me explain I am being attacked by there 25 clan troops plus on top of those 25 troops an additional 245 troops for a total of 270 troops, this has to be a cheat of some kind, I haven't heard of this happening to anyone else yet, but I know I am not crazy, well maybe just a little. thanks for your time.

Comment: wow I am going to the loony bin. Thank you for setting me straight

Comment: @ianRussell It's ok.  When I first started noticing that nuance, it threw me off as well.  I'm not sure why Supercell displays it this way, or if it is even intentional.  If you found this answer helpful, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

After re-building your Clan Castle, you have the option to join a Clan. After joining you can ask for Troops to be donated to your Castle from the other members in your clan, depending on what level your castle is reflects how many troops it can house. These troops can be used to attack other village clans in addition to your regular clan army. they can also be used to defend your village from other attackers, this works when any of the attackers army comes contact with your castle perimeter what ever troops you have housed automatically get sent out to defend your clans village.

Comment: You must have miss understood.  I am part of a clan level 87 with 2900 trophies. my question is I can only attack with 220 house spaces worth of troops + my 25 from my clan, but I am being attacked by 25 troops from their clan and up to 245 housing spaces worth of troops, how are they doing this? Thank You for your response.